# Stop to finish all threads before starting new threads c# 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating many threads using below method

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                            //do some task here
                            });
```

In some point of time I want to execute a method but before that I want to

1. Ensure that all currently running threads are get finished.
2. Ensure if there is any call to create new thread should wait and not lost.
3. After my method is executed start all waiting threads.

Any good solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

--------------------Edited Code-----------------------

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Thread @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        });
    }
```

When we reach to this call this should check any pending tasks before executing

Console.WriteLine("*******************Called Another Method***********************");

When above is being executed and another request is coming same as below then it should only start after above line (in my case method) is executed.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second Thread @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        });
    }
```

Comment: Try using the CountdownEvent Class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(VS.100).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So, you want to have two type of tasks: first type can run concurrently, and second type should run exclusively?

Comment: I want that when I call a method suppose methodA() it should check if there is any thread running.  It will wait to finish running threads but In between if any new request comes to create new threads same using Task.Factory.StartNew it should wait and not lost.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to implement some sort of Queue that executes the work in a single thread. Here's some minimal implementation (untested!)

```
class QueuedWorker 
{
    ConcurrentQueue<Action> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();  
    ManualResetEvent waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    Thread workerThread;

    public QueuedWorker() 
    {
        workerThread = new Thread(ThreadWorker);
        workerThread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadWorker() 
    {
        Action nextTask;

        while(true) 
        {       
            while(queue.TryDequeue(out nextTask)) 
            {
                // run the queued task
                nextTask();
            }

            waiter.WaitOne();   
            waiter.Reset();
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(Action item) 
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        waiter.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have edited my question.  Could  you please suggest here ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem my self by storing tasks created into a list and applying lock on it.

```
 class Program
        {
            static List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StartTasks("First"); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadMethod(); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StartTasks("Second"); StartTasks("Third"); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadMethod(); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StartTasks("Four"); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadMethod(); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StartTasks("Five"); StartTasks("Six"); StartTasks("Seven"); StartTasks("Eight"); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadMethod(); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StartTasks("Nine"); StartTasks("Ten"); });
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadMethod(); });

                Console.WriteLine("Execution is completed !");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public static void LoadMethod()
            {
                // Lock and wait to not allow any thead to modify the list
                lock (taskList)
                {
                    if (taskList.Any())
                    {
                        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
                    }

                    Debug.WriteLine("*******************Called Another Method***********************");
                    taskList.Clear();
                }
            }

            public static void StartTasks(string taskName)
            {
                lock (taskList)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        var t = new Task(() =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(taskName + " @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        });
                        taskList.Add(t);
                    }

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskList.ForEach(task =>
                    {
                        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                        {
                            task.Start();
                        }
                    }), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            }
        }
```